# Off-center camera projection for 3d illusion using LibGDX

Tags: android, opengl, 3d, libgdx

I'm trying to achieve this 3d pop out of the screen kind of effect using LibGDX on Android (the camera process described at the given link):

https://www.anxious-bored.com/blog/

but the result I get is stretched objects when the eye moves around.

I simulate the eye position using a gyroscope to get device rotation and assume a fixed distance from the device screen. I've also incorporated ARCore for eye tracking, but that also yields the same result.
Here is a GIF of what I'm seeing:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOf6n.gif

Anyone have any idea on what I'm doing wrong?
Here is the relevant code I'm using in Kotlin.

```
private fun updateCamera() {
        val camera = // The Perspective camera instance

        // Move the camera to the eye position, but keep the same camera direction
        camera.view.setToLookAt(camera.direction, camera.up).mul(GDXHelperInstances.matrix4_1.setToTranslation(GDXHelperInstances.vector3_1.set(camera.position).scl(-1f)))

        // Get the size of the screen in meters
        val deviceHalfHeight = camera.viewportHeight / Gdx.graphics.ppcY * 0.01f
        val deviceHalfWidth = camera.viewportWidth / Gdx.graphics.ppcX * 0.01f

        // Get the device position and plane relative to the camera
        val pos = Vector3(Vector3.Zero).mul(camera.view)
        val plane = Plane(GDXHelperInstances.vector3_1.set(camera.direction).scl(-1f), Vector3.Zero)

        // Calculate the bounds of the viewport in virtual space (the device screen dimensions in meters with center at Vector3.Zero) relative to the camera (view space)
        val left = pos.x - deviceHalfWidth
        val right = pos.x + deviceHalfWidth
        val bottom = pos.y - deviceHalfHeight
        val top = pos.y + deviceHalfHeight
        val nearScale = camera.near / plane.distance(camera.position).absoluteValue

        // Off-axis projection
        camera.projection.setToProjection(left*nearScale, right*nearScale, bottom*nearScale, top*nearScale, camera.near, camera.far)

        // Calculate new asymmetrical frustum
        camera.combined.set(camera.projection)
        Matrix4.mul(camera.combined.`val`, camera.view.`val`)
        camera.invProjectionView.set(camera.combined)
        Matrix4.inv(camera.invProjectionView.`val`)
        camera.frustum.update(camera.invProjectionView)
}
```